# MySQL find duplicates but coalesce column data without deleting rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of 1 million plus records where I need to find duplicates, and change a column's value, flagging them, without deleting the row, but also keep the other column values. So, for example:

```
id email     addr        city   state zip phone        active
1  me@me.com 1234 Street Denver, CO 80012 123-555-6789 1
2  me@me.com BLANK BLANK BLANK, CO BLANK BLANK         1
```

So I need to keep row 1's column values, and switch row 2's active field to 0, without deleting it. Is this doable in MySQL? Needs to be somewhat fast, or it will crash the box, having 1 million+ rows. I can use PHP, but if possible, MySQL only would be far better.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I have a list of duplicates, but I can't find something that can compare the 2 rows and either pick the right one to deactivate, or copy over the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that determines uniqueness is the column email (as is suggested by your example) then Try this:

```
 Update t set active= 0
 From Table t
 Where id !=
     (Select Min(id) From table
      Where email = t.email)
```

If other columns should also be used to determine uniqueness , then inmclude those in the subquery  where clause:

```
 Update t set active= 0
 From Table t
 Where id !=
     (Select Min(id) From table
      Where email = t.email
         And addr = t.addr
         And [Other columns])
```

To deal with issue in your comment,  If there are blank fields, and you want to collect the data from multiple rows, you have a much more complex problem.  First of all, there may be more than one row with values, and then may be different for some rows than for others.  Second, if you want to include them in your test for uniqueness (for duplicates) only when they are populated, then what dio you do when some rows have three columns the same and a different set of rows have a different set of columns with the same values?

```
 id    addr   city    state    zip     phone 
  1     X     Denver   CO     71113    Blank
  2     Y     Blank    CO     Blank    212.901-3456
  3     X     Denver   TX     Blank    Blank
  4     Y     ElPaso   TX     Blank    212.901-3456
  5     X     ElPaso   Blank  71113    Blank    
  6     Y     ElPaso   Blank  Blank    212.901-3456
```

How do you then decide what rows are duplicates ? This is too complex to deal with.  If you could settle on a fixed set of columns to be used to determine uniquenses/dupllicates, then there is a way to gather the data values for the other columns from one of the other multiple rows which you are deactivating when the one you are leaving active has a blank value,  but if the columns to be used to determine uniqueness/duplicates can be different, (depend on the actual data values), then these techniques will not work.

Comment: How does this account for fields that have data? They are not always the first row, so I need to be sure it doesn't lose those values in case they are in row 2.

Comment: This would work if there was a value in every row like address. The problem is that I don't know whether there is an address, but if there is, I want to keep it, so the query needs to make a dynamic decision based on the presence of data on which row to deactivate.

Comment: If there's more than one row with data with same email address, do you want the first entry, the most recent entry or entries to be merged as a new entry?

Comment: @SamiKorhonen It depends on which row has the other fields, address, zip, phone, etc.

Comment: You need to explain rules for marking row as inactive before complete answer can be provided.

Comment: The rules are: only the row with field values should be active, and all duplicates (matched on email field only) should be deactivated. Sometimes there is no field data (so either row is fine), but when there is, it needs to be kept.